# Jenkins - Hide sensitive data from pipeline steps page (flowGraphTable)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a sensitive data to a .yml file as a string in my Jenkins groovy file. I have attached the .groovy file which would show what I am trying to achieve but it reveals the data in Pipeline steps which is also attached. Nothing shows in the console log. Value from AWS Parameter store is retrieved and passed as a string to a .yml file and this string value is shown in the pipeline steps. I am looking for a way to hide this from being shown in the Pipeline steps. I have tried using `set +x` but it is not hiding the string value in the pipeline steps. Any thoughts on how this can be achieved would be of great help.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGjv2.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

properties([
    parameters([
        string(name:'NODE_NAME', defaultValue: 'node', description: 'Node Name')
        ])
])

nodeName = params.NODE_NAME

node("${nodeName}") {

    def AWS_REGION = "eu-west-2"
    def paramPath = "path"
    def paramName = "PASSWORD"

    stage("Data from SSM") {
        param = sh (script: "aws ssm get-parameter --name ${paramPath} --with-decryption --region ${AWS_REGION} | /var/jenkins_home/tools/jq .Parameter.Value | tr -d '\"'", returnStdout: true).trim()
        sh('#!/bin/sh -e\n' + "echo '${paramName}: ${param}' >> vars.yml")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of credentials in jenkins. Go to Jenkins -> credentials -> global -> add credentials

Select either 'Username with password'/'secret text' depending on your need

This will generate a secret in jenkins

Then in your groovy file you can use the credentials as env variables which will not be printed by jenkins

```
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Your-Credential-ID', passwordVariable: 'pwdToken', usernameVariable: 'userToken')]){
   //Use pwdToken as a variable here which will not be printed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back. Used readFile and writeFile to hide. Still I am looking at a way if by some scripting means it can be accomplished for the line ''' sh('#!/bin/sh -e\n' + "echo '${paramName}: ${param}' >> vars.yml") '''

Comment: I think running this command inside the `withCredentials` block should hide the password